# MySQL Error Files

Tags: php, sql, database, mysql

How To resolve this?

Chown? 
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of`/var/lib/mysql/denora': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/anope': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of`/var/lib/mysql/test': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/Animachat.svipchat.org.err': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of`/var/lib/mysql/vpsgabriel.svipchat.org.err': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of`/var/lib/mysql/mysql': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/wp': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of`/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0': Operation not permitted

MysqlD Start?

[root@SSH mysql]# sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

Log MySQLd:

```
140129 09:39:37 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140129  9:39:37 [Warning] '--safe-show-database' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use 'GRANT SHOW DATABASES' instead.
140129  9:39:37  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140129  9:39:37  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140129  9:39:37  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
140129 09:39:37 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140129 09:40:05 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140129  9:40:05 [Warning] '--safe-show-database' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use 'GRANT SHOW DATABASES' instead.
140129  9:40:05  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140129  9:40:05  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140129  9:40:05  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
140129 09:40:05 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140129 09:42:02 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140129  9:42:02 [Warning] '--safe-show-database' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use 'GRANT SHOW DATABASES' instead.
140129  9:42:02  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140129  9:42:02  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140129  9:42:02  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
140129 09:42:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140129 09:44:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140129  9:44:55 [Warning] '--safe-show-database' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use 'GRANT SHOW DATABASES' instead.
140129  9:44:55  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140129  9:44:55  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140129  9:44:55  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
140129 09:44:55 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: -1 for not reading the log: `The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.`

Comment: Chmod ? chmod: changing permissions of `Animachat.svipchat.org.err': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `anope': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `denora': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `ib_logfile0': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `ib_logfile1': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `ibdata1': Operation not permitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that runs the MySQL daemon doesn't have permission to write to your database directory.

If you're using a standard installation with default settings, the following command should fix that (*edited to add sudo based on your edited output: if you can run as `root`, leave off the `sudo`*):

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

You can find exactly what user it is (if it's not `mysql`) by looking for the `user=` option in `/etc/my.cnf`, or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Comment: Prefix the `chown` with `sudo`. I've edited based on your output.

Comment: [root@SSH mysql]# sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1': Operation not permitted

Comment: Is `/var` mounted from a network share? Is it a read-only file system?

Comment: Run `mount` and see if something comes up beginning with `/var` to see if /var is mounted from a network share. The output should also show you if it's mounted read-only because you'll see `ro` instead of `rw` in the output.

Comment: [root@SSH mysql]# mount
/dev/ploop23328p1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,barrier=1,dat                        )
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptnone on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relat

Comment: I Am Running CentOS 6.2.

Comment: Try "setenforce 0" and then re-run the command in my answer.

Comment: [root@SSH mysql]# setenforce 0
setenforce: SELinux is disabled

Comment: Well I'm out of ideas. You need to fix the permissions problem before you fix the MySQL problem.

Comment: i Reinstall CentOS 6.2 =( Thanks!

Comment: It might also be caused by apparmor if your datadir is not in the default location. Check /etc/apparmor.d/usr/sbin/mysqld and add the path there.